# Which version of using statement is correct or safest?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, using-statement

Both versions I and II of the 'using' statement below work, but I have a suspicion that the first version only works because the C# garbage collector in Visual Studio 2010 has not deleted the variable "context" (a Entity Framework variable). On the other hand, I got the first version from off the net from a seemingly reputable source, so I assume it's OK?

**VERSION I:**

```
try
{
    using ( AnEFEntity context = new AnEFEntity()) //note: no curly brackets!
    using (var ts = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
    {
        // stuff here that uses variable context
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

// the above compiles fine and works fine—but is the first ‘using’ statement in scope?  Seems so but it’s suspicious.

**VERSION II:**

```
try
{

    using ( AnEFEntity context = new AnEFEntity())
    { //note a curly bracket used for first ‘using’
        using (var ts = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
        {
            // stuff here that uses variable context
        }
    } //note the placement of the second curly bracket for the first 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

// the above also compiles fine and works fine—is it more safe than the first version?

Comment: Your second version only has a single using statement. Please edit your question to show what you really meant. I *think* I know, but I don't want to put words into your mouth, so to speak.

Comment: Note to future readers: move the slider bar to get the full code--don't know why the formatting is off, but there are two using in both versions.

Answer (score 9):

It makes absolutely no difference to the compiled code, because the body of the outer `using` statement is just inner `using` statement. Personally I *usually* prefer to put the braces in, because then it's clearer what's going on if you want to introduce more code between the start of the outer `using` statement and the inner `using` statement. However, indentation can make this clearer as well. The code in your question is hard to follow because it's not indented at all, whereas I'd use the two formats like this:

```
using (...)
using (...)
{
    // Body
}
```

vs

```
using (...)
{
    using (...)
    {
        // Body
    }
}
```

The risk of the single-brace version is that you end up writing this accidentally:

```
using (...)
    Log("Hello");
using (...)
{
    // Body
}
```

At that point the code no longer does what you want in terms of execution flow. This will *usually* lead to a compile-time error because the second `using` statement would normally depend on the resource declared in the first, but not always.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  BTW I bought one of your books on LINQ and liked it.

Comment: @PaulDecember: I don't have any books on LINQ... do you mean C# in Depth? Or did you download Edulinq?

Comment: --sorry I meant C# in Depth, which has an appendix on LINQ which is where I first learned LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

same effect here also,Braces are used if mutiple lines are there, if only a single line then no need of that but for readability you can use it

```
                bool firstcondition = true;
                bool secondcondtion = true;
                if (firstcondition)
                    if (secondcondtion)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("inside");
                        MessageBox.Show("inside");
                    }
```